# If $z_0$ is a solution for $z^{13}-13z^7+7z^3-3z+1=0$, does also $\bar z_0$ is a solution?

Tags: complex-numbers

If $z_0$ is a solution for $z^{13}-13z^7+7z^3-3z+1=0$, does also $\bar z_0$ is a solution for the equation?

I dont realy have an idea, i would like a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take conjugate on both sides. Use the facts that conjugate of $a+b$ is the sum of the conjugates of $a$ and $b$ and the conjugate of $z^{n}$ is the $n-th$ power of the conjugate of $z$.

Comment: Do you mean, doing like: $\overline{z^{13}-13z^7+7z^3-3z+1} = \bar{z}^{13}-13\bar{z}^7+7\bar{z}^3-3\bar{z}+1$? and what does it give me?

Comment: @Alon It gives you $\bar0=0$ if $z=z_0$.

Comment: @Alon Now just substitute $\;z=z_o\;$ in your equality...what do you get?!

Comment: but its for the conjugate equation, not for the original one, so i conclude that for the conjugate, i get for $\bar{z_0}$, that it is true, but what about the original equation?

Comment: @Alon First put $z=z_0$ and then take the conjugate on both sides. The equation you get says that $\overline {z_0}$ is also a solution of the same equation.

Comment: Oh its because its the conjugate *on both sides* so what solves the equation for the conjugate on both sides, will solve the original equation as well, namely doing cojugate on both sides doesnt change the equation solutions?

Comment: @Alon Yes, this argument works for any polynomial equation with real coefficients. It does not work for complex coefficients.

Comment: So lets say, for equation like $z^2+iz+2 = 0$ and we know that $z_0$ solves it, so, by the same logic, take the conjugate on both sides, and we get as well that $\bar{z_0}$ also solves it, is that true?

Comment: @Alon No. The problem is $\overline {iz} =-i\overline {z}$ and not $i\overline {z}$.

Comment: Ok,now i understand the connection to $\overline{a+ib} = a-ib$ thank you for the help.